# Firebase authentication - console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

how to find out if a user is authenticated using the console? I'm not sure if it can be checked directly, I haven't found a way to check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of users you can find a specific one by searching by his exact `uid` or `email` likere shown on the screenshot:

[image]

Have in mind that the Search field is not like a normal one. It will show only results if you enter the whole `email` correctly or the whole `uid`